# How do I mount a qcow2 disk image?

Tags: mount, virtualization, qemu

I have a QEMU virtual machine that uses a qcow2 disk image.

How can I mount its filesystem without powering on the virtual machine?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A quick google search turns up the [`qemu-nbd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/qemu-nbd.8.html) program, mentioned [here](http://alexeytorkhov.blogspot.com/2009/09/mounting-raw-and-qcow2-vm-disk-images.html). It is part of the `qemu-kvm` package, so you'll have to install KVM if you aren't using that already. Not sure about any direct GNOME/KDE solutions, if that is what you were looking for. Here is an example for using it:

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 --read-only /path/to/image.qcow2
udisksctl mount -b /dev/nbd0p1
```

Comment: Looks like `qemu-nbd` is the best way to go, as long as I remember to `modprobe nbd` first. `qemu-nbd` fails *silently* if this module has not been loaded!

Comment: That's unfortunate. You should be able to add `nbd` to `/etc/modules`, anyway.

Comment: I wrote a little tool to wrap this up: https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/qcow2-explore

Comment: `qemu-nbd` is part of the [`qemu-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qemu-utils) package, so no need to install KVM

Comment: I must appreciate this very nice, yet simple and powerful answer. It helped me to resolve my issue in a couple of minutes. Thank you Tim Yates.

Answer (score 4):

There's also *libguestfs*, but it's not yet available from official repositories[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/667346).  There are binaries in [libguestfs.org](http://libguestfs.org/download/binaries/) though.

Comment: While libguestfs looks really nice, but is heavyweight. It has a ton of dependencies (It recommends up to **55** dependencies, and installs an entire `supermin` appliance.

Answer (score -1):

`xmount` can make the disk images of some VMs look like a raw disk (which can then be partitioned with `losetup`, and the partitions mounted). I don't know if it supports qcow2, however.

Comment: The [xmount manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xmount.1.html) states that only EWF and raw disk images can be used.

Answer (score -2):

you can directly mount as a normal mount like this

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mount-point
```

But if u have n number of device mean you want again mount it to another directory for 
that you can follow this one:

Mounting a partition from raw image is pretty simple:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 image.img
kpartx -a /dev/loop0
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/image
```

Comment: A qcow2 image is *not* a raw image, and can't be mounted through either of those approaches.