# Please explain the concept behind installing ubuntu as an .img file?

Tags: networking, mount, virtualization

I am trying to understand why the ubuntu  server is setup as an .img file within my NAS "/Public” directory.

I created a VM on my NAS and installed  ubuntu server within the VM.
When I installed ubuntu server I installed it in my NAS "/Public” directory.
FYI, ubuntu installed fine.  I can access the file system via ssh and have set up my web server just fine.

However, I cannot figure out how to access the ubuntu file system using my laptop.  Where is it hiding?
I looked inside my  NAS "/Public” directory.  but all I see is a ubuntu_server.img.

I researched on the internet but, I cannot seem to understand the concept of why an .img file was created when I installed ubuntu.

1. Could someone please explain the concept here?
2. I would also like to access my ubuntu server files using my laptop.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

VMs have disks that they present to a guest and those are either backed by a full real disk/partition or backed by an image file which in your case seems to be the case.

There are [various subtle details formats possible](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/images.html) in your case most likely either *raw* format (as it is .img) or *qcow2* (another common option). You can check that with `qemu-img info <path-to-your-file>`.

Now to mount those (and please only do that when the guest it *NOT running* or the filesystem might go corrupt) you can do depending on that format:

- raw: [Unable to Mount .img file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110467/unable-to-mount-img-file)
- qcow2: [How do I mount a qcow2 disk image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4396/how-do-i-mount-a-qcow2-disk-image)

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to install ubuntu as a .img file? follow these steps;

1. Download the desired .img file.
2. Install the USB-image writer package.
3. Open Applications -> Accessories -> Image Writer.
4. Insert your flash media.
5. Choose the downloaded file and flash device, and click "Write to Device"
6. Remove your device when the operation is complete.